# In Lone Wolf, why does 7 and 13 signify everlasting death in life, and evil power respectively?

Tags: lone-wolf, magnamund

According to [Lone Wolf wiki](http://lonewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Vashna):

> Vashna, also known as Darklord Vashna, was the leader of the Darklords
>   and their most powerful member. ... ... The number ninety one was that
>   of Vashna which he chose because of its factors, seven and thirteen.
>   Seven to signify the everlasting death in life and life in death he
>   possesses and thirteen to denote the power of evil at his command.

I've read all the action books, but I don't think this was ever elaborated on.

Comment: 13 is likely just because it's been considered an unlucky number in Western culture for some time now. I wouldn't have a clue about 7. Nice to see a *Lone Wolf* question though.

Comment: Good point. I suspect that 7 may be intended as an inversion of the 7 Lorestones, but it's a very tenuous link. It's such an underrated series! Unfortunately, I think it will be difficult for it to make a comeback considering that the people who used to read game books probably play Skyrim now.

Comment: I loved game books, and miss them dearly. It's possible the number 7 refers to the 7 Doomstones, which were created to act as an evil counter to the Lorestones. I hadn't thought of that until you mentioned the Lorestones.

Comment: That's an excellent theory, good catch!

Comment: Note that you can (legally) download all of the gamebooks here; http://www.projectaon.org/en/Main/AllOfTheBooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference itself can be found in [The Sacrifice of Ruanon](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1260818.The_Sacrifice_of_Ruanon) and isn't explained further:

> There are ninety-one priests in all, Lone Wolf, said his Kai voice
>   inside him. It seemed to have been a long time since he had heard its
>   dustily cool tones. The number ninety-one was that of the Darklord
>   Vashna, who chose it because of its factors, seven and thirteen –
>   seven to signify the everlasting death-in-life and life-in-death that
>   he possesses, and thirteen to denote the power of the Evil at his
>   command.
>
> These are the aspects of Naar that he was able to call upon to serve
>   his will while he walked upon Magnamund; they will become his slaves
>   once more should the Darklord be reborn.

The sole reference within either the novels or the gamebooks that connects the numbers seven and thirteen is from [War of the Wizards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Wizards_(gamebook)). There are 13 magical powers in total, of which the first seven are described as the "lesser magicks".

> *There are thirteen Magical Powers, the first seven of which are called
>   the Lesser Magicks*
>
> - **Sorcery, Enchantment, Elementalism, Alchemy, Prophecy, Psychomancy, Evocation.**

The Higher Magicks are:

> - **Thaumaturgy, Telergy, Physiurgy, Theurgy, Visionary, Necromancy**

The implication seems to be that unlike the player (who must select their abilities from the list) Vashna has mastery of ***all*** of the types of magick, both the seven and the thirteen.

Comment: I am amazed at some of the things you comment on. I loved this series growing up and owned all of the choose-your-own-adventure books. Did not even know there were novels.